# Is it appropriate to say “happy valentines day” to a colleague?

Tags: coworkers

By colleague, I mean the client of my company who I work for.

There is no romantic intention whatsoever, I simply want to be nice.

In terms of my proximity of relationship to the person, the client (female) is an older person, and we have met in person but mostly only exchange emails.

If you don’t think it’s appropriate (or there is a risk that it’s interpreted as a romantic advance), what could you say alternatively?

Comment: Hey Hmlet. Can you expand on why you want to wish a coworker a "happy valentines day?" Or what you're trying to communicate with that? And when/what situation this would come up? Without knowing what you're trying to mean, it's difficult to come up with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to add the context, my apologies. I have added it - hopefully it clarifies now - but if there is anything else I can add that would be helpful, please let me know.

Comment: It could be very inappropriate if that person happens to be single. Have you made sure your client is in a relationship ? If you happen to know by name the person she is with, adding that precision could make it a more clear and personalized message (Happy valentine's day to you and X).

Comment: Can you also explain what you're looking for when you ask about 'what to say alternatively'? What message do you want our help conveying to this woman? Also do note that per [help/on-topic] "Other types of questions that are off topic include questions that: ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say."(somewhere near the bottom, easily missed ;) ). Perhaps this is better off without that whole part, and focused on the etiquette of who you can wish a happy valentines day and how?

Comment: In addition to what Tinkeringbell said, can you add whether you are male (otherwise not sure why you'd mention her gender), and a location tag?

Comment: Since there's a bunch of questions in the comments I've voted to close, but once you have a chance to [edit] it'll go into a queue where users can vote to reopen it :)